# Sceneform - How to make the camera view too autofocus

Tags: android, android-studio, sceneform

So, the default camera view in sceneform is in fixed focus settings. But its blur and doesn't feels good. I want to get the camera to show everything clearly (Autofocus mode).

I tried changing the session config. But it is not really working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 override fun getSessionConfiguration(session: Session?): Config {
    val config = Config(session)
    config.focusMode = Config.FocusMode.AUTO

    return config
}
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for. It works well. But this affects the performance by a large amount. I think its better to work with the fixed focus mode as long as we are not using any view that close. And thanks for the help :)